# Why was the optional assertion message in assertEquals moved to the last position in Junit 5?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, junit5

In JUnit 4, the optional assertion message was the first parameter in the assertEquals method. In JUnit 5, it's the last.

Is there any technical reason why it was moved to the last position? And if so, which?

Comment: The simple answer is that the junit 5 authors decided so. Maybe they liked the TestNG-style assertions. An explanation might be that now it's easier to add a message to an existing `assertEquals`.

Comment: I don't know whether that was the actual reason, but all other things being equal, it's good practice to put the optional parameters last.

Comment: @Nicolai this also sort of "complies" with other libraries, guava `Preconditions` do that, `Objects#requireNonNull`, looks like a common pattern

Comment: This question is either answered in an offsite resource or primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Maybe we could reopen the question, so that one of the authors of JUnit 5 can give the authoritative answer: https://twitter.com/johanneslink/status/994809931067949056

Comment: @joschi reopened.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'll try to clarify our thought process when designing the JUnit 5 API (now manifested in the Jupiter test engine) 3 years ago. The others who were present at the time (Marc Philipp, Sam Brannen, Matthias Merdes and Stefan Bechtold) may chime in and correct my memories...

We had a few basic constraints:

1. The JUnit 5 API should - from a compiler's perspective - be completely separate from older versions, so that tests from different versions could stand side by side
2. Nevertheless, the API should *feel* familiar in order to make migration easy
3. The API should incorporate state of the art and good practices of Java API design

Deciding that the optional message argument of all assertion methods in `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions` will always be last was a trade-off between points 2 and 3. This made even more sense as we allowed `Supplier<String> messageSupplier` arguments. Using lambda expressions in the first position of an assertion statement would look strange and distracting - so we thought.

Judging from hindsight I'd probably argue for a more radical change of the assertion API in order to forgo confusions of the kind touched in this question. I'd even push for not using `@Test` as the primary marker for test methods considering how often JUnit Jupiter newcomers import the old `org.junit.Test` annotation and wonder why the system is behaving strangely.

Comment: I confirm the rationale supplied by Johannes. ;-)

Comment: In general, we try to always define method signatures so that _optional_ parameters come after required parameters.

Comment: It makes sense, but maybe you can elaborate on the rationale for #1. Usually libraries want to make the newer version backward compatible, but #1 is almost the opposite goal. Thanks.

Comment: @Max Going from JUnit 4 to what we then saw as our vision of JUnit 5 in a backwards-compatible step by step way would have required lots of inbetween stepping stones - and probably taken years. So we decided to break compatibility but allow both versions at the same time for migration. In retrospect I think it was the right call.

Comment: This did make test migration much more difficult than it needed to be and was a flawed choice in my opinion. If you wanted the Junit 5 and 4 to be used side by side why not just have preface each method call in JUnit 5 with ju5. For example ju5AssertEquals(int expected, int actual, String message).  This would have enabled far more intuitive migration while being easier to differentiate one versions calls from another visually and semantically.

Answer (score 0):

This would be required to ask the authors themselves, but it's a common pattern across other libraries.

Guava `Preconditions#checkNotNull` for example, or even the JDK itself in `Objects#requireNoNull`. It sort of makes sense for that optional parameter to be the "last one" IMO (but that's opinion based of course).

Comment: One of the authors wants to answer the question, but cannot, because the question was put on hold by you and others.